# L.Control.Search: Using looping for searching data on Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

Is there a way to find data from different layers and different `propertyName`s? I have several GeoJSON data files, with different properties. At this moment I can only search one GeoJSON.

For looping and calling the data I am using this code:

```
maplink_var = [source1.geojson,source2.geojson,etc]; 

var <?= $i['maplink_var']; ?> = new L.GeoJSON(<?= $i['maplink_var']; ?>, {
  style: function(feature) {
      ...
    },
  onEachFeature: function(feature, marker) {
      ...
    }
});
```

and below is the code to find data:

```
var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
  layer: source1,source2,source3,
  propertyName: ['propNameSource1','propNameSource2','propNameSource3'],
  marker: false,
  moveToLocation: function(latlng, title, map) {
    var zoom = map.getBoundsZoom(latlng.layer.getBounds());
    map.setView(latlng, zoom); // access the zoom
  }
});

searchControl.on('search:locationfound', function(e) {
  e.layer.setStyle({fillColor: '#3f0', color: '#0f0'});
  if(e.layer._popup) e.layer.openPopup();
}).on('search:collapsed', function(e) {
  featuresLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) { 
    featuresLayer.resetStyle(layer);
  }); 
});

map.addControl( searchControl );
```

I get an error if I give array on property name, stack on loading, and none of the data appears.

[image]

Comment: Please share the exact error message. Also: I don't know the `<?= ... ?>` syntax. What does it mean? Is it some kind of PHP?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: leaflet-search.js:103 . prop.split is not a function ... <?= ?> is same as <?php echo ?>. at the top i using foreach for looping and get variableName from database.

Comment: Line 103 is inside a function called `_getPath`: Line 103 in file src/leaflet-search.js at stefanocudini/leaflet-search - https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/master/src/leaflet-search.js#L103 Not sure what to make of it, but it might be because you are passing an array to `propertyName`.

Comment: You sound like you either have a data issue with 10's-100's of different datasets or a code issue trying to accommodate all these different types. Have you thought of a workflow process to consolidate these datasets into one unified database. It may make your coding easier and data management issues go away. If the data is not constantly changing, something that does field mapping on import might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search#options) `layer` is a `L.LayerGroup`. Thus you can pass multiple layers like this ([source](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search/blob/8fb13e2b7e9e8fbe2554be3879ea2248e4847c3a/examples/multiple-layers.html#L78)):

```
var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
  layer: L.layerGroup([source1, source2, source3]),
  ...
})
```

As for the `propertyName`: The property name must be the same for all GeoJSON files. Try this when you create the `L.GeoJSON` (not tested):

```
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
  const p = feature.properties
  p.title = p.propNameSource1 || p.propNameSource2 || p.propNameSource3 //create new property 'title'
}
```

`title` is the default for `propertyName` so you won't even have to set it when you create `L.Control.Search`.

Comment: yes. if i have same propertyName is no problem. but i have 100 layers and really bad if i must change all the origin data for add new propertyName. so can we handle it w/o change the origin data? on my layers only propertyName.ID has an equation data

Comment: Can you distinguish the `propertyName` from the other feature properties somehow? E.g. is it the only string property? Does it contain some pattern? Then you could fill `p.title` with that field that matches the pattern.

Comment: i can handle it use your code with my method. thanks before

Answer (score 0):

Here is a map I created that uses JQUery's autocomplete for searching.

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/senate/index.html

I use the select's label and value, the label is the name, value is the layer. Since I set the leaflet layer_id to be the polygon's feature NAME, There is a one to one match. So when they select a name, it knows what polygon and layer to highlight and switch to.

In the ForEachFeature setting the poly ID to feature name:

```
layer._leaflet_id = feature.properties.NAME;
```

Pushing the NAME and layer to an array:

```
arr1.push({label:data.features[i].properties.NAME, value:"senate"});
```

Grabbing the select value:

```
polySelect(ui.item.label);
```

Firing off the selected NAME, to "select it and zoom to it"

```
map._layers[a].fire('click');
var layer = map._layers[a];
map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
```

It's a different method then you went down but I'm tossing it out as an option. I have a page for school I made, it may help, the above example is from the NY Leg Map, and their is also a simple JQuery Autocomplete (search) write up there. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/

Comment: this is for 1 type only? i mean i have ex 10 layer with different property name. how to handle it? for layer i can handle it using L.layerGroup([source1, source2, source3]). but cannot for propertyName, I testing 1 by 1 property name and working fine, but when i try to pass it into the array. i got an error like my image at the top

Comment: Since I grabber the layer name, I could use that in a switch statement to get the right field to search on.