# GeoJSON search box for multiple layers

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson

I am wondering how to make the GeoJSON search more efficient. I would like to get the search result from more than 1 layer in GeoJSON.

My code is (I attached one of two GeoJSON examples):

```
var test = [{
"type": "Feature",
             "properties": {
             "Title": "Waterbeach Church",
                 "Head": "Chapel Street",
                 "Description": "Parish community"
        },
            "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
            0.192763,
            52.263692
                ]
                  }
                    }];

var geojsonMarkerOptions2 = {
radius: 5,
fillColor: "#ffc34d",
color: "#1a1100",
weight: 1,
opacity: 1,
fillOpacity: 0.4
};

var church = L.geoJSON(test, {
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions2);
},
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup('<h1><u><font color="red">'+feature.properties.Title+'</h1></u></font><h2>Address: '+feature.properties.Head+'</h2><p>'+feature.properties.Description+'</p><a>'+feature.properties.URL+'</a>');
}

    }).addTo(map);
```

Afterwards, I am using Leaflet GeoJSON control search, where I want to search between both multiple geoJSON layers (already solved using this link:

[L.Control.Search: Using looping for searching data on Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306645/l-control-search-using-looping-for-searching-data-on-leaflet)

and for their property features. I am interested in search for more than 1 properties.

When I place another value in "propertyName", then query is redirected to this 2nd value instead of 1st or both.

```
L.control.search({
layer: L.layerGroup ([sitis, church]),
initial: false,
propertyName: 'Title', 'Head' // Specify which property is searched into.
  })
  .addTo(map);
```

Can I have something like:
    propertyName: L.GeoJSON.PropertyGroup (['Title', 'Head', 'Description]),

Or is there another reasonable solution for this issue?

Comment: Please add also second GeoJSON example to your question.

Comment: It's exactly the same. The name is only different, but properties are the same:

It's not enough space to do it here unfortunately. 

var sitis = {...GEOJSON file THE SAME feature properties (only different names)...}

var GeoJSONMarkerOptions - exactly the same values, only colour and radius slightly different...

My GeoJSON properties contains:
Title
Head
Description

I would like to have them searchable

Comment: I was asking for it just to be sure properties are the same in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is based on Leaflet.Control.Search plugin example [Search markers with Fuzzy Search](https://labs.easyblog.it/maps/leaflet-search/examples/fuzzy.html), which uses [Fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/) library for searching objects by keywords in properties.

The key steps to make possible search on two properties of two GeoJSON layers are:

1. At the time of creating GeoJSON layer, define new feature property `myKey`, which combines both properties we want to search: `Title` and `Head`. This property will be used for search and for displaying search suggestions.
2. Create `fuse` search object on the basis of concatenated GeoJSON objects. Object are concatenated so that there is only one sorted search list. There are various search options possible. Below example searches beginning of words, with at leat two characters required to start search.
3. Create `searchControl` for searching, with `filterData` option where search is done with the help of `fuse` search.

```
var sitis = L.geoJSON(test1, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    feature.properties.myKey = feature.properties.Title + ', ' + feature.properties.Head
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions2);
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('<h1><u><font color="red">'+feature.properties.Title+'</h1></u></font><h2>Address: '+feature.properties.Head+'</h2><p>'+feature.properties.Description+'</p><a>'+feature.properties.URL+'</a>');
  }
}).addTo(map);

var church = L.geoJSON(test2, {
  pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    feature.properties.myKey = feature.properties.Title + ', ' + feature.properties.Head
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, geojsonMarkerOptions2);
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup('<h1><u><font color="red">'+feature.properties.Title+'</h1></u></font><h2>Address: '+feature.properties.Head+'</h2><p>'+feature.properties.Description+'</p><a>'+feature.properties.URL+'</a>');
  }
}).addTo(map);

var fuseOptions = {
  shouldSort: true,
  tokenize: true,
  threshold: 0,
  location: 0,
  distance: 100,
  maxPatternLength: 32,
  minMatchCharLength: 2,
  keys: ['properties.myKey']
};

var fuse = new Fuse(test1.features.concat(test2.features), fuseOptions);

var allLayers = L.layerGroup([sitis, church]);

var searchControl = new L.Control.Search({
  layer: allLayers,
  propertyName: 'myKey',
  marker: false,
  filterData: function(text, records) {
    var ret = {}, key;
    var jsons = fuse.search(text);
    for(var i in jsons) {
      key = jsons[i].properties.myKey;
      ret[key]= records[key];
    }
    return ret;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you.

It works, very similarly to the simple one, however without this code:

    marker: false,
      filterData: function(text, records) {
        var ret = {}, key;
        var jsons = fuse.search(text);
        for(var i in jsons) {
          key = jsons[i].properties.myKey;
          ret[key]= records[key];
        }
    return ret;
  }

When I add up the code above, then search box is not viable. It looks like still something is missing there.

Comment: @tomazicM thanks for the method. Just one confusing area--concatenating geojson features: should test1.features be test1._layers? There is no features attribute on my geoJSON layers. Concat doesn't seem to work on _layers though.