# QGIS2web layer search for more than 1 layer

Tags: qgis, javascript, openlayers, qgis2web

I would like to expand my layer search on another 2 or 3 layers.

In the qgis2web.js file, I found the following section:

```
    var searchLayer = new SearchLayer({
     layer: lyr_Area_5B_Chamber_14,
     colName: 'Chamber No',
     zoom: 10,
     collapsed: true,
     map: map
    });
```

which corresponds to 1 layer only.

I would like to add another layer.

The thread here is for Leaflet, but states about the `Layergroup` option:

[GeoJSON search box for multiple layers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330867/geojson-search-box-for-multiple-layers)

but if I apply to my example it doesn't work

```
  var searchLayers = L.layerGroup([lyr_Area_5A_Pole_13, lyr_Area_5B_Chamber_14])

  var searchLayer = new SearchLayer({
  layer: searchLayers,
  colName: 'Chamber No', 'Pole No.',
  zoom: 10,
  collapsed: true,
  map: map
  });
```

as well as in the following case:

```
  var searchLayer = new SearchLayer({
  layer: lyr_Area_5A_Pole_13, lyr_Area_5B_Chamber_14,
  colName: 'Chamber No', 'Pole No.',
  zoom: 10,
  collapsed: true,
  map: map
  });
```

Is there any way to expand the layer search in QGIS2web plugin?

**UPDATE:**

I tried sth like this

```
  var searchLayer = new SearchLayer({
  layer: lyr_Area_5B_Chamber_14 || lyr_Area_5A_Pole_13,
  colName: 'Chamber No' || 'Pole No.',
  zoom: 10,
  collapsed: true,
  map: map
  });
```

with the OR operator. Unfortunately only 1 layer comes

Comment: your example is using OpenLayers, not Leaflet. Have a look at the documentation of the search plugin here: https://github.com/webgeodatavore/ol3-search-layer but it might not be possible with OL

Comment: Yes, I did. The problem is, that there is an example with still 1 layer only, whereas I need them at least 2.

Comment: When exporting using OpenLayers as library with QGIS2web, it is this plugin that is used for the search tool. But it looks like the plugin doesn't allow to have 2 or more searchable layers so you'll have to improve the plugin yourself, or code something from scratch, or use an other plugin like https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/search/map.control.searchfeature.html or use Leaflet as library as the answer you mention seem to work with it.

Comment: I would rather use openlayers for this map. The operators also don't work

Comment: Yes, I checked the plugin and it can't work with two layers in its current form, no matter the syntax. "layer" as to be a ol.Layer object so impossible to put 2 different there. OL doesn't have a native search function so you'll have to code one or find an other plugin.

Comment: I was trying to code as per above. Unfortunately the issue must lie in the core code somewhere I guess